# Difference between mien, comportment, demeanour

Tags: word-difference

Can anybody construe the differences between mien, comportment and demeanour?

When is it better to use each of them?

Well, here are definitions from google SERP

mien - a person's appearance or manner, especially as an indication of their character or mood
"he has a cautious, academic mien"

comportment - behaviour; bearing.
"he displayed precisely the comportment expected of the rightful king"

demeanour - outward behaviour or bearing.
"his happy demeanour"

I understand each definition, but for me, they all can be replaced with `behaviour`, and yet they exist in English. Why? Can you describe situations when `behaviour` is not enough?

Comment: This COULD BECOME a good question with proper editing. The place to start is a dictionary (you can use English language Google or Bing). After giving the basic definitions, you can then say what you find confusing. That helps us know what to discuss.

Comment: Two are quasi-synonyms, one is not. There's also Merriam Webster, the Oxford Dictionary online and the Cambridge Dictionary online.

Comment: In practice, most native speakers would rarely if ever use *any* of these three words. We usually say ***appearance*** rather than ***mien***, and ***manner, behaviour*** rather than ***comportment, demeanour***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

""Mien" and "demeanor" mean much the same thing, but I would tend to use "mien" when discussing facial appearance coupled to behavior or environment. That is, I would be likely to use "mien" rather than "demeanor" in a sentence like **His cautious, academic mien dissolved into a broad smile.** I would tend to use "demeanor" relative to physical appearance more broadly. **Although his words were pacific, his whole demeanor was military.** But "demeanor" need not refer to physical appearance, but to social behavior. **I did not initially believe them guilty because their demeanor was so casual and apparently carefree.**

I tend to use "comportment" to mean appearance that reflects reality. **His demeanor was judicial** means to me that he gave the appearance of being judicial without indicating whether or not he actually was judicial in his rulings. **His comportment was judicial** means to me that his appearance and his rulings were what is to be expected of a judge.

Comment: comportment is really just behavior....I have never seen it to mean appearance of a behavior.

Comment: Personally, I think the "near-synonyms" are ***demeanour*** and ***comportment***, in that they both tend to refer to *consciously controlled* movement/behaviour (usually, with the specific intention of conveying a certain impression). But ***mien*** tends to refer to *appearance* (often, just the *facial* aspect) insofar as it reflects one's state of mind, even in contexts where the subject is unaware of this and/or not trying to control his appearance.

Comment: @Lambie I am not really sure whether we are disagreeing. If a judge did not appear to be judicious in her physical manner in court but her decisions were well reasoned and equitable, I would not say that her comportment was judicial. Justice must be done and be seen to be done. But behavior has two aspects,  one involving appearance and one involving substance. I would not use **comportment** unless both aspects of behavior were present. I was not advising (or at least not trying to advise) to equate comportment with mere outward show.

Comment: Judicious or judicial??

Comment: @FF I obviously do not agree that **demeanor** and **comportment** are synonyms (see my comment to Lambie), but I do agree that **mien** does not imply conscious effort whereas **demeanour** tends to do so. There may be differences in usage between the U.S. and the U. K.

Comment: @Lambie I meant **judicious.**

Answer (score 1):

Although all three words refer to conduct, behavior, and manner, both **mien** and **demeanor** are neutral in the sense that one's mien or demeanor could be pleasant or surly, slovenly or neat, whereas **comportment** usually suggests a degree of self-control and acting within the bounds of propriety.

We can say "a surly mien" or "a surly demeanor" but not "a surly comportment".